# Group By Pandas Datframe and Get Counts

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a simple question but somehow I am not getting the results.

My data looks like:

```
Pagename UserId
A           X
B           X
C           Y
A           X
```

My question is this:

I want my data as:

```
UserId  PageName Count
 X         A      2
 X         B      1
 Y         C      1
```

I know how to get this in SQL, but how to do it in Pandas?

I keep getting the error: `ValueError: No axis named user_Id for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

for `df.groupby('name', 'user_Id').size().reset_index(name='Count')`

and data

```
                                     name                 timestamp
user_Id
buD00         Clicked Back to List Button  2018-05-20T11:00:00.035Z
cWH00    Clicked Create New Ticket Button  2018-05-20T11:00:00.051Z
huB00     Clicked Ticket Reference Number  2018-05-20T11:00:00.067Z
hOH00     Clicked Ticket Reference Number  2018-05-20T11:00:00.067Z
```

Comment: `df.groupby('Pagename', 'UserId').size().reset_index(name='Count')` ?

Comment: need `df.groupby(['Pagename', 'UserId']).size().reset_index(name='Count')`

Comment: @HarvIpan ValueError: No axis named user_Id for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Comment: @jezrael I get the error ValueError: No axis named user_Id for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Comment: I think need `[]` in groupby

Comment: Is it `UserId` or `user_id`? Also, is `user_id` an index?